# How to update collation in database created by grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
  dataSource {
       dbCreate = "update"
       url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc"
  }
```

Here GORM creates a database named 'abc' when first the application runs. By default, the database has a collation property latin1_swedish_ci. I want the collation of this database to be utf8_general_ci when first created by GORM.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have an example with Unicode and UTF-8:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

If still getting error then create database as

```
CREATE DATABASE database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```